# Find date from a string based on date format Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, parsing

I have a sting which contains multiple dates. I need to find a specific date based on the provided date format.

sample string : 'this string has two dates 03-13-2023 08:09:16 and 2023-03-15 19:54:02'
I need to extract date with format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S': 03-13-2023 08:09:16

Please note that the date format is provided at runtime and could change dynamically based on each execution. In short, during execution I have a string and intended date format using which I have to find date from string which matches the given date format.

There are articles suggesting regex being used for finding date from string. But in those scenarios format of date to find is constant. In this case, I don't have a fixed date format as it is provided at runtime.

Comment: Do the strings only have dates in the dynamically given format seperated by spaces? And do these date formats sometimes have spaces in them (so that one can't simply do a split on whitespace to identify the first date)? If so (and I am guessing because you don't give enough info) you could maybe write a function to count the spaces in the dynamically given format and adjust the split accordingly

Comment: could you please show  a [mre] and something you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a very naive approach, but you could hack together a function that converts date formats to regex. Something like the following. I'm sure this ends up being death from a thousand edge cases, but perhaps it works out ok. Then with regex in hand, you can use `re.findall()` or what-have-you to pick dates out of strings.

```
import re
def datetime_format_to_regex(dt_format):
    r_format = dt_format
    dateformat_to_regex={
        '%Y':'[0-9]{4}',
        '%y':'[0-9]{2}',
        '%m':'[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%b':'JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC',
        '%B':'JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER',
        '%d':'[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%a':'MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN',
        '%A':'MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY|SUNDAY',
        '%j':'[0-3]{1}[0-9]{2}',
        '%w':'[0-6]{1}',
        '%H':'[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%I':'[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%M':'[0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%S':'[0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}',
        '%f':'[0-9]{6}',
        '%p':'AM|PM',
        '%Z':'[A-Z]{3}',
        '%z':'(\+|\-)[0-9]{4}',
        '%U':'[0-5]{1}[0-0]{1}',
        '%W':'[0-5]{1}[0-0]{1}',
        '%C':'[0-9]{2}',
        '%G':'[0-9]{4}',
        '%u':'[1-7]{1}',
        '%V':'[0-5]{1}[0-0]{1}',
        '%c':'MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN\sJAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC\s[0-3]{1}[0-9]{2}\s[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}:0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}:0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}\s[0-9]{4}',
        '%x':'[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}/[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}',
        '%X':'[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}:0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-6]{1}[0-9]{1}\s[0-9]{4}',
        '%%':'%',
        ' ':'\s',
        '.':'\.',
        '(':'\(', 
        ')':'\)'
    }

    for k,v in dateformat_to_regex.items():
        r_format = r_format.replace(k,v)
        
    return r_format

date_formats = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S']

for date_format in date_formats:
    regex_date_format = datetime_format_to_regex(date_format)
    for found in re.findall(regex_date_format, 'this string has two dates 03-13-2023 08:09:16 and 2023-03-15 19:54:02'):
        print(f'Date "{found}" using date format "{date_format}"')
```

---

```
Date "2023-03-15 19:54:02" using date format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
Date "03-13-2023 08:09:16" using date format "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I tried with *dateutil parser* but found the performance to be inconsistent. PFB one scenario where it  failed : 

    `from dateutil import parser`
    `print (parser.parse('bla bla Thursday, 25. September 2010 10:36 AM - bla bla bla'))`

Hence I finally decided to create a function similar to @JNevill suggested which converts date format into corresponding regex and find matching value within string.

Comment: I was really hoping someone would find a more elegant way to pull this off. Regex is definitely the right tool, but I'm surprised there isn't a module that is more polished than this to pull this off.